# Type value mismatch error with vectors

Tags: c++, types, vector, mismatch

I get the following error message when I try to run my program:

```
 main.cpp|44|error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template
 parameter list for 'template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class
 std::vector' main.cpp|44|error: expected a type, got '(render)3u'
 main.cpp|44|error: template argument 2 is invalid main.cpp|44|error:
 invalid type in declaration before ';' token
 === Build finished: 4 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===
```

And here is my code for main leading up to the error causing line:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<GL/freeglut.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "include/Block.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "include/TextBlock.h"
#include "include/Enemy.h"
string text;
stringstream ss;
enum render {Normal,SelectRangeText,SelectSText,Enemy,EnemyTypeSelection};
enum render state;
enum type { Foreground, Background, Midground };
enum type selected;
enum types { Blocks, Enemies, Text };
enum types special;
string names[4]  = { "grass" , "smallGrassBlock" , "dirt" , "sand" };
void createEnemy(int,int);
void addEnemyWaypoint(int,int);
void addToList(vector<Block> &list,int x,int y);
void placeText(int x,int y);
void initTextures();
GLint GetTexture(string file);
void IdleFunction();
void removeBlock(int x,int y);
int xOffset,yOffset,multiuse = 0;
using namespace std;
string to_string(int number);
void placeBlock(int x,int y);
void drawBitmapText(char *string, float x, float y, float z);
void reshape(int w, int h);
void render(void);
void keyboard(unsigned char c,int x,int y);
void mouse(int button,int state, int x, int y);
void arrows(int key, int x, int y );
std::vector <Block> backBlockList;
std::vector <TextBlock> textBlockList;
std::vector <Block> midBlockList;
std::vector <Block> foreBlockList;
std::vector <Enemy> enemyList;//error occurs here
GLuint  textures[1];
unsigned int screenXSize=800;
unsigned int screenYSize=800;
unsigned int selectedBlockType = 1;
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
```

The header for enemy:

```
#ifndef ENEMY_H
#define ENEMY_H
#include<GL/freeglut.h>
#include <vector>
class Enemy
{
    public:
        Enemy(int Type );
        virtual ~Enemy();
        void render(int,int,GLuint);
        void addWaypoint(int,int);
    protected:
    private:
        int type;
        std::vector <int> X, Y;
        int xsize,ysize;
};
#endif // ENEMY_H
```

And the constructor for enemy:

```
Enemy::Enemy(int Type)
{
    xsize=30;
    ysize=30;
    type=Type;
}
```

However it will run corrrectly if I substitute the type of my vector to an int.
When the following line is commented out: std::vector  enemyList; it compiles, however if it's there it doesn't
when declaring an Enemy like this 
Enemy e(5);

it runs correctly

Updates: 
If i change the enemy header, and cpp  to something like the following:

CPP:

```
#include "../include/Enemy.h"


Enemy::Enemy( )
{

}


Enemy::~Enemy()
{
    //dtor
}
```

Header

```
#ifndef ENEMY_H
#define ENEMY_H

class Enemy
{
    public:

        Enemy(  );
        ~Enemy();

    protected:
    private:

};



#endif // ENEMY_H
```

It still crashes with the same error, this means it must be something in main

FIX: 
For some reason when I declare it in the line above my enums it works, however if below it doesn't, I have no idea why. If someone could explain this please go ahead.

Comment: std::vector <Enemy> enemyList;//error occurs here

Comment: Can you reduce this to a minimal test-case, so that we don't have to wade through all that other code?

Comment: There is the header, and constructor for Enemy, and there is the include statement for main (#include "include/Enemy.h"), and the declaration of an Enemy object vector(std::vector <Enemy> enemyList;//error occurs here).

Comment: Don't know.  All looks fine.  My guess is there is something else going on that you haven't put up here causing the issue.  Start commenting out things within Enemy.h and see if you can isolate it that way.  Perhaps try declaring an Enemy outside of a vector as well and see if that works.

Comment: note the fix to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a `vector` of some value type, the type must have an available no-argument constructor, which yours doesn't (ie. that's what the error message is telling you). However, since I doubt you want to copy around `Enemy`s, you should store them by pointer,ie.

```
vector<Enemy*> enemies;
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ENEMIES; ++i)
    enemies.push_back(new Enemy(type));
```

**EDIT** I just noticed you have the following declaration

```
class Enemy...
```

but you also declare an enum value

```
enum render {... ,Enemy, ....
```

I just compiled the following code and got a *suspiciously* similar error:

```
#inlcude <vector>


class A {};

enum type {A, B, C};

std::vector<A> As;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  return 0;
}
```

So there's your problem. When it comes time to resolve the template, the compiler sees an enum value (which can be a template parameter, just like any other integral type), and assumes that's the one you meant. However, since no vector template matches (they all have a class as the first template parameter), it doesn't compile. Hence, your error.

Comment: That's untrue. It only requires default-constructibility for some functions. Also, your disgusting use of raw new appals me.

Comment: That is wrong and you shouldn't use the keyword new in that way. Don't comment incorrectly on things that you know nothing about.

Comment: @user1814893: Given that it's *your* code that isn't working, that kind of response seems somewhat hypocritical...

Comment: @Oli: His criticism of `new` is surprisingly accurate, given the otherwise terrible code in the OP.

Comment: The use of new like that was to try to keep the example as brief as possible. If I knew people would take it so personally I would have written it differently. @DeadMG, I was under the impression that every method of the template class needs to compile for it to work. Given that your answer is functionally equivalent, I don't understand the harshness of your criticism.

Comment: I'm sorry- after reading what I said I realize it came out a little snarky. Trust me that was not my intention

Comment: @user1814893 I found your actual problem, in no small part because your sincerity convinced me to take a better look at your code.

Comment: Thank you very much, while I had already fixed it I did not know the reason. That's a good thing to know for future knowledge.

Comment: Voted up to negate the negative - The response has been updated; the former versions weren't bad either; This response was chosen as answer.

Users should refrain from bitching without pitching. If it doesn't fit the preferred format, but resolves the issue, then write a comment or answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

For some functions, `std::vector<T>` requires that `T` be default-constructible. Your `Enemy` class cannot be default-constructed, therefore the compiler issues an error. Either define a default constructor for `Enemy`, do not call `vector` functions that require default constructibility, or change the `vector` to be of a different type.

Given the `virtual` use in Enemy, and that `std::vector<Enemy>` could never accept a derived class, plus your use of disgusting global variables, C arrays and otherwise terrible code, I am going to posit that you have no idea what is going on.

A `std::vector<Enemy>` can only ever hold an `Enemy`. It cannot hold a derived class of `Enemy` or anything else. It can only hold `Enemy`. If you wish to have a `vector` of things that might be various derived classes, you must use a pointer of some degree of ownership. This means you must solve the problem of who owns the objects being pointed to, and further that you must understand the concept of ownership and what smart pointers are available. This is essential knowledge for C++ and you won't get far without it.

Comment: It does not hold a derived class of enemy, Enemy is not a super class it is just an independant stand alone class. Enemy just needs to hold vectors of waypoints, and a type (int). In regards to being default constructible then why can I make vectors of the following Block::Block(int type, int X,int Y) or TextBlock::TextBlock(int X, int Y), you can see in the segments i have created vectors of these and it compiles fine.

Comment: @user1814893: If it's not a superclass then why does it have a virtual destructor? Those are only useful for superclasses. In any case, vector only requires default-constructibility for *some* functions (not all). Simply declaring the Enemy vector should not be illegal. You need to reduce your code to remove all the noise and only showcase the problem.

Comment: that is the way codeblocks sets up the destructors on creation of the class, I did not notice this but will change it in the future